# Set marker and Display Button on Google Map android app

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an android application at in one of the activities I display the Google map with help of the following pieces of codes

```
 public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.fragment_map);       
   }
 }
```

And my fragment file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

the version of my play services is `7.3.0`
and this is part of my `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
```

}

**Question:** I need to point a marker on the map before rendering the map in the application, I also need to display 2 simple button on the map as well. 
how should I modify my code to get it working?

I have already some similar questions, but haven't found my answer they either have chosen to render the map in a different way or using another version of Google play services. so please provide a detailed answer

Comment: Sounds like you need to put your map in some kind of container or view, and have the buttons on the outer view

Answer (score 3):

To add marker, in your onCreate(),

```
 MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
             googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
        }
    });
```

To add buttons, in your layout file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: this function `getFragmentManager()` is not recognized inside `MyActivity` how should I call this function?

Comment: It should be recognising. Check whether 'MapFragment' is 'SupportMapFragment'. If that is the case, you should use 'getSupportFragmentManager()'